# MVVM Command property stacktrace

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I'd like to know which property command is executed using the following pattern in my ApplicationCommand, any idea ? Today the Log always show ApplicationCommand.Execute(), not very usefull to trace user actions.

Class declaration :

> ```
> public class MyViewModel
> {
>     public ICommand BlinkCommand { get; set; }
>     public ICommand CheckCommand { get; set; }
>
>     public MyViewModel()
>     {
>         BlinkCommand = new ApplicationCommand(() => DoBlink());
>         CheckCommand = new ApplicationCommand(() => DoCheck());
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

My application command implementation for all commands :

```
public class ApplicationCommand : RelayCommand
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            // No try-catch, I never code bugs ;o)
            Log.Info("Prepare to execute the command " + this);
            base.Execute();
            Log.Info("Finished to execute the command " + this);
        }
    }
```

Using 1 command = 1 class, it's fine. Using this way, which seems to be widely used on the WWW, I don't know how to proceed :(

Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor your `ApplicationCommand` like this:

```
public class ApplicationCommand : RelayCommand
{
    string commandName;
    public void Execute()
    {
        // No try-catch, I never code bugs ;o)
        Log.Info("Prepare to execute the command " + commandName);
        base.Execute();
        Log.Info("Finished to execute the command " + commandName);
    }
    public static void SetCommand(MyViewModel vm, 
                                  Expression<Func<MyViewModel,ICommand>> commandSelector, 
                                  Action action){
       var me = commandSelector.Body as MemberExpression;
       if(me == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid command  selector!");
       var newCommand = new ApplicationCommand(action);
       newCommand.commandName = me.Member.Name;           
       vm.GetType()
         .GetProperty(newCommand.commandName)
         .SetValue(vm, newCommand, null);
    }
}

//then use it like this
public MyViewModel()
{
    ApplicationCommand.SetCommand(this, e => e.BlinkCommand, () => DoBlink());
    ApplicationCommand.SetCommand(this, e => e.CheckCommand, () => DoCheck());
}
```

I understand that it's for debugging purpose, so we should print the property name and then using the approach above is better.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay, I decided this choice of implementation for my future application. A kind of command factory which will enable easy macro record/play for UT.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try call GetType()?

```
public class ApplicationCommand : RelayCommand
    {
public ApplicationCommand(Expression<Func<ICommand>> property,Action<T> execute, string logName = "")
{
    // ...
    this.logName = logName;
}
        public void Execute()
        {
            // No try-catch, I never code bugs ;o)
            Log.Info("Prepare to execute the command " + GetTypeName(this.GetType()) + "." + GetPropertyPath(property));
            base.Execute();
            Log.Info("Finished to execute the command " + GetTypeName(this.GetType()) + "." + GetPropertyPath(property));
        }
    }

private string GetPropertyPath(LambdaExpression propertyPath, bool acceptsFields = false)
    {
        Stack<MemberInfo> properties = GetPropertyPathStack(propertyPath, acceptsFields);
        return string.Join(".", properties.Select(p => p.Name));
    }

private Stack<MemberInfo> GetPropertyPathStack(LambdaExpression propertyPath, bool acceptFields = false)
    {
        MemberExpression member = propertyPath.Body as MemberExpression;
        Stack<MemberInfo> properties = new Stack<MemberInfo>();

        while(member != null)
        {
            if (member.Member is PropertyInfo || (acceptFields && member.Member is FieldInfo))
            {
                properties.Push(member.Member);
                if (member.Expression is MemberExpression)
                {
                    member = member.Expression as MemberExpression;
                }
                else
                {
                    ConstantExpression constant = member.Expression as ConstantExpression;
                    member = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                member = null;
            }
        }

        return properties;
    }

private string GetTypeName(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                return GetGenericTypeName(type);
            }
            else
            {
                return type.FullName;
            }
        }

    private string GetGenericTypeName(Type type)
    {
        Type[] genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
        string argumentNames = string.Join(", ", genericArguments.Select(GetTypeName));
        return string.Format("{0}<{1}>", type.GetBaseName(), argumentNames);
    }
```

Hope, this will help you or inspire you for better solution.

Usage:

```
BlinkCommand = new ApplicationCommand(() => BlinkCommand, () => DoBlink());
```

Comment: I tried it to be sure, but the instance I'm creating are all of type "ApplicationCommand" so they only return the same type. No indication about source property, doesn't work :o(. Thanks anyway for your help. By the way I'll keep your code, I play too often with generic and non generic types, may be usefull :)

Comment: @user1886795 I modified my answer. Now you can log name of source property too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll choose the King King solution which is less intuitive but with a better orientation on my needs

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra instance string to the ApplicationCommand that you pass when constructing an instance and log that when execute is called.

```
public class ApplicationCommand : RelayCommand
{
    private string logName;
    public ApplicationCommand(Action<T> execute, string logName = "")
    {
        // ...
        this.logName = logName;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        // No try-catch, I never code bugs ;o)
        Log.Info("Prepare to execute the command " + this.logName);
        base.Execute();
        Log.Info("Finished to execute the command " + this.logName);
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
BlinkCommand = new ApplicationCommand(() => DoBlink(), "Blink");
```

Comment: I was thinking about an identifier like this (string, int, ...). It could be the only way if I don't find another one. But would be painfull for other features I'd like to have like record and play commands (I will have to browse all view models and all commands to discover them).Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user1886795 - By making the logName parameter optional as I did, you don't have to search through all of your code. You just add it where you want.

Comment: I'm gonna have to register for all commands to listen their execution and aprameters. Then I'll try to execute them automatically in the same order the user did it during execution ==> for bug tracking and no regression. I'm used to do this with another architecture. With this one, I'd like to find a nice way to get the same feature without any/much impact on code and using a formal way. I'm looking both approach of King king and user 2250152.

Comment: Next time put this kind of information in the question. You will get much better answers and suggestions.